# save button in android programing

Tags: android, button, layout, save

hey guys I'm working on an android project and I want to add a button in my app that when user click on it,it save an image in res to sdcard and it shows a toast "image saved in sdcard"
please help me

Comment: @ShifarShifz an image from drawable

Comment: Answer updated with new feature *Showing Notification After Save Success"; Thanks for the idea @VasyaFromRussia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          saveImage(true);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",0).show();
});
```

and the saveImage();

```
public void saveImage(boolean isNotifyAfterSave){
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush(); 
    outStream.close(); 

    //if isNotifyAfterSave = true, then it will show an NotificationAlert.
    if(isNotifyAfterSave){
        Uri uriOfFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
        showNotification("Image Saved","desc:ic_launcher.png","IMAGE SAVED!",uriOfFile);
    }

}

public void showNotification(String title, String text, String ticker,Uri pathToImage) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, pathToImage);
    intent.setDataAndType(pathToImage, "image/*");

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    nBuilder.setContentText(text);
    nBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    nBuilder.setTicker(ticker);
    nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    nBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify);
    nBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
}
```

Don't forget to add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

REF: StackOverflow

Comment: You are welcome,:) , MARK THE ANSWER AS THE CORRECT ONE, so people wil able to find solution asap.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shifar Shifz's answer. If you want to see your image in gallery after saving, you should call method like this:

```
 private static void addImageToGallery(final Context context, final String filePath) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Otherwise it may be available only with file manager, not gallery app.